# Error when saving entity with UDT user defined type in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, user-defined-types, spring-data-cassandra

I have a UDT in my Cassandra entity :

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table("schedule")
public class ScheduleEntity {
@PrimaryKey
private InstantKey key;

@Singular
@Column("days")
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UDT, userTypeName = "schedule_day")
private List<Day> days;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@UserDefinedType("schedule_day")
public static class Day {
    @Column("day")
    private DayOfWeek day;

    @Singular
    @Column("periods")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UDT, userTypeName = "schedule_period")
    private List<Period> periods;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@UserDefinedType("schedule_period")
public static class Period {
    @Column("from_time")
    private Long from;

    @Column("to_time")
    private Long to;

    @Column("x")
    private BigDecimal x;
}
}
```

When I try to use save entity using save method from CassandraRepository, I get this error in my unit test :

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042] Cannot connect), localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
```

I dont have this problem with find methods, any idea please !
PS : the insert query passe without problem :

```
insert into schedule (id, year, instant, days)
values (99, 2018, '2018-04-16T16:44:49Z', [{day: 'MONDAY', periods: 
[{from_time: '9:00:00', to_time: '18:00:00', setpoint: 24.3}]}]);
```

Comment: btw, Spring-data-cassandra not really optimized for work with Cassandra. You can achieve the same functionality using the DataStax java driver

Comment: what version of spring-data-cassandra are you using ?

Comment: I use spring-data-cassandra 1.5.9

Comment: Problem solved by removing CassandraAutoConfiguration.class from my config and injecting the Cluster bean from the session